# remove object from JSON array by id after delete from DB

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json array that looks like:

```
var ad =[{"itemID":"195","issue":"first","buttonText":"First","date":1481200571","link":"https://example.com/link"},{"itemID":"197","issue":"other","buttonText":"Something Else","date":1481200571","link":"https://example.com/linkother"},{"itemID":"215","issue":"main","buttonText":"Important","date":1481200571","link":"https://example.com/linkmain"}];
```

(The above example has 3 objects, but in reality it could have many more.)

And I have an ajax action on my page that will delete the row from the db that one of these objects represents. Rather than refresh my page with the entire json which is many rows and a db call, I would like to just permanently remove the object that is represented by `itemID` from the array in my page using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it.

The ones that come to my mind:

1. filtering out an item:

   ```
   ad = ad.filter(item => item.itemId != 'DELETED ID');
   ```
2. finding index of an item and removing it

   ```
   var deletedItem = ad.find(item => item.itemId == 'DELETED ID');
   ad.splice(ad.indexOf(deletedItem), 1);
   ```

Comment: will option 2 permanently remove it? I ask because I have other js on the page that filters the array for other purposes, and I want to make sure that item will no longer be found at all...

Comment: second option will modify `ad` "by reference". If other parts of yours application are using the same reference it means that they will use the updated version.

Comment: use `findIndex` instead of `find` and `indexOf`